# Split Datatable with large column into Child Datatables columnwise with one column fixed

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, linq-to-dataset

I have large datatable with atleast 50 columns.

> first column contains the description of row data

i.e In 1st column, row data is the header for the rows so

> i want to keep the 1st column

Large Datatable must be split into child datatable after every 10 columns maintaining the first column values

> 1st column of parent layout must retain in all child datatables

. Please suggest best possible solution. Thanks.

Comment: Create dataviews with the columns you need

Comment: Thanks for comment. dataviews played best role to complete the requirement